# Propagate Spring Cloud OpenFeign custom errorDecoder to client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, circuit-breaker, openfeign

I want to make custom errorDecoder and throw the error to the client.

FeignClient:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "department",
    url = "${external.resource.department-url}",
    configuration = DepartmentClientConfig.class
)
public interface DepartmentClient {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    JsonNode getDepartment(@PathVariable("id") Long id);
}
```

CustomErrorDecoder:

```java
public class DepartmentClientErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {

        return switch (response.status()) {
            case 404 -> new DepartmentNotFoundException("Department Not Found");
            case 503 -> new DepartmentServiceNotAvailableException("Department Service is unavailable");
            default -> new Exception("Exception while getting departmentId");
        };
    }
}
```

DepartmentClientConfig:

```java
public class DepartmentClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
        return new DepartmentClientErrorDecoder();
    }
}
```

I use a `@RestControllerAdvice` to handle those error:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(DepartmentNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleDepartmentNotFound(DepartmentNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return buildErrorResponse(ex, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }
}
```

When I don't define a FallBack, it throws a `NoFallBackAvailableException`. But when I define one, the error won't  return to the client.

How do I return the error to the client?

Comment: If you are using a circuitbreaker, that error won't make it to the client. What does the fallback do?

Comment: The fallback just return a dummy JsonNode.

Comment: what versions are you using?

Comment: Java: 17, spring-cloud 2022.0.3